# The [fridge] should be a tag synonym for [refrigerator]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[fridge](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fridge) should be a synonym for [refrigerator](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refrigerator)

This should be an obvious tag synonym, but hasn't happened yet...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out. Looks like tester101 created it, and I just approved the [synonym](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tags/refrigerator/synonyms).